# Apache cxf jax-rs implementation with xml databind

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I configured my rest service to implement content negotiation through Variant.
On jersey all works fine but on apache cxf something goes wrong.

*No message body writer has been found for class ContentType: application/xml*

It seems thath when I construct the response as xml type it cannnot find the correct body writer.

I configured jax-rs with jacksonJaxbJsonProvider and all works great with json databind.

```
<jaxrs:providers>
  <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
</jaxrs:providers>
```

cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs version 3.0.3
jackson-databind: 2.4.2

Any idea?

Comment: Let us see your jaxb class

Comment: @XmlType(propOrder = { "orderId"})
public class OrderForConfirmationEmail implements Serializable {  @XmlElement
  public long getOrderId()
  {
    return orderId;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `@XmlRootElement(name="order")` generated xml cannot be `<orderId>data<orderId>`, it should have root element.  Thus updated code would look like

```
@XmlRootElement(name="order")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "orderId"})
public class OrderForConfirmationEmail implements Serializable {


    @XmlElement
    public long getOrderId() {
        long orderId = new Random().nextLong();
        return orderId;
    }

}
```

Generated xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><order xmlns="http://com.kp.swasthik/so/schema">
   <orderId>369317779145370211</orderId>
</order>
```

and json is

```
{"orderId":6812414735706519327}
```